# Eclipse will not run when JDK is specified in eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

Eclipse will not run when I specify where the JDK is location on my machine. has this happened to anyone before? I've read similar answers to questions like this but they haven't been helpful. When I remove the path to the JDK it works fine. This is the content of my eclipse.ini *

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\javaw.exe
```

*

Attached is also an image to prove  I'm pointing to the right location.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your -vm Entry is simply wrong. Right:
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\
A directory path to the bin directory whithin a vm installation is expected.

Comment: but I'm asking about the JDK?